# Jekyll Child Page Navigation

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I'm finishing up my site redesign and just need to complete my portfolio page. Rather than using posts for portfolio entries, I want to use subdirectories/child pages:

```
...
work
  project
     index.html
  project-2
    index.html
  index.html
...
```

I want to loop through those subpages in a list to show on `work/index.html`.
Something similar to:

```
<ul>
  {% for page in site.work.pages %}
    <li>
      <figure>
        <img src="/img/foo.jpg" alt="foo">
      </figure>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll does not support this as simply as in your example yet, [it is coming in 2.0 however](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1941).

You could add a key/value pair to the YAML header of the child pages to signify that it should appear on the main index page. I have a similar setup that I use to define what pages should appear in the main navigation for the site.

#### project/index.html etc

```
---
group: work
---
```

#### work/index.html

```
<ul>
{% for node in site.pages %}
    {% if 'work' == node.group %}
    <li><a href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You may be able to avoid requiring the group attribute if you changed the if condition to do substring matching of the URL, but this solution is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you do your own page build with `jekyll build` you can simply create a file called `_plugins/page_filters.rb` with the following contents:

```rb
module Jekyll
  module PageFilters
    def children_of(all_pages, parent)
      all_pages.select { |p| child_of?(p, parent) }
    end

    private

    def child_of?(child, parent)
      parent_path = parent["path"]
      child_path = child.path

      # Exclude 'index.md' from becoming a child of itself
      return false if parent_path == child_path

      # Remove 'index.md' from the parent path
      parent_path = parent_path.split("index.md", 2).first

      child_path.start_with? parent_path
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::PageFilters)
```

And then invoke the `children_of` filter as such:

```
{% assign children = site.pages | children_of: page %}
<ul>
{% for child in children %}
    <li><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```